# PHP extends DOMDocument not accepting $config array

Tags: php, class, properties

This example (I need to extend `DOMDocument`) shows the problem: `var_dump(config)` returns `NULL` (!), but there is an initialization.

```
class DOMxDocument extends DOMDocument {
    public $X = 22;
    public $config = array(
       'a' => false,
       'b' => true
    );

    public function __construct($newconfig=NULL) {
         print "X={$this->X}\nY:";
         var_dump($this->config); // NULL!!
         parent::__construct("1.0", "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Seems to work perfectly fine](http://codepad.org/FJ4CcKLb), even on PHP 5.2.

Comment: Sorry, I edited is a problem with DOMDocument and the var name "config"...

Comment: Sorry, bad question... Now I find, manual say that is a *deprecated* property of DOM, and it is read only, so I can not use this reserved name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$config` is apparently used internally by `DOMDocument`, whose constructor itself initializes it to `NULL`.

Choose any other name.

Comment: YES, $config2 is valid, thanks!  But the question now is "WHERE IT WAS DOCUMENTED?"... Hum... I find something: `readonly public DOMConfiguration $config;` at [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)